# Twilio Programmable Chat Mute Notifications by Channel

Tags: chat, twilio, twilio-api

We are using Twilio Programmale Chat and we need to allow people to mute/unmute notifications on a channel by channel basis (like Slack).

Is it possible? this is critical to us right now.

Thank you

Comment: Right now we can only send to all or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

PM from Twilio here. Good news: this feature has been added to the product with the [User-Channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/user-channels) REST resource (specifically `NotificationLevel`), or on the Channel object on the first-person [iOS](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/chat/releases/2.4.2/docs/Classes/TCHChannel.html), [Android](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/4.0.1/docs/classcom_1_1twilio_1_1chat_1_1Channel.html#a3455c5aaac5e4a4972415011276ff2af), and [JavaScript](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.2.0/docs/Channel.html#setUserNotificationLevel__anchor) SDKs. That notification level expresses one particular user's preference within the given channel.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid [Programmable Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat) does not currently allow you to mute notifications on a channel by channel basis. It is on the roadmap for the future though.

Comment: Thanks @philnash we need it for next week, what can we do? :/ thanks

Comment: For now your option is probably to handle notifications yourself. You could do so by turning them off on Twilio's end and then subscribing to the [`onMessageSent` webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/webhooks#post-callbacks) and sending your own notification depending on the mute status of the channel.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? I want similar functionality for mute notification particular channel.

Comment: There is no update that I know of myself (and I’m on holiday right now). Your best bet is to email help@twilio.com and see if they can help or put you in touch with the Chat team.